MS Word for Mac breaks ?" across lines in web layout
Experienced MSW user, but this one has me stumped.
In my usage, there seems to be a wrapping problem in web layout (only) such that a question mark followed by a closing quote is split when at the end of the window.
example the problem with identification of font and style
I've tried different fonts and font sizes, different templates (including default), and different styles (including normal). I've also reinstalled MSO.
There was similar (unresolved) question some months back, in that case incorrectly splitting a word.
What have I not tried? What am I missing?
Thanks all.
